# Convert PHP request to Python

Tags: python, php, python-requests

I have this PHP code

```
$url = 'http://11.111.11/index.php/Api/xxx/';
$data_post = http_build_query(
                            array(
                                'key1' => 'KEY'
                                ,'company1' => 'company'
                                ,'period1' => 'period1'
                            )
                        );

    $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'content' => $data_post,
            ),
    );
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents( $url, false, stream_context_create( $options ) ));
```

But I don't know PHP, and I need to use it in Python. I've tried several things and I get a response [200], but I think I am passing the parameters wrong as I only gent an error in the json.
This is what I've tried with request:

```
import requests

url = 'http://11.111.11/index.php/Api/xxx/'
data = data = {'key1':'KEY'
                'company1': 'company',
                'period1': 'period1',
                 'header': "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
r = requests.post(url, headers = data)
```

and this is what I've tried with urllib and I get a response [500]

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = urlencode({'key1':'KEY'
            'company1': 'company',
            'period1': 'period1',
             'header': "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
             'method': 'POST'}).encode("utf-8")

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
r = urlopen(req, data)
```

Comment: if you can post your PHP request to httpbin.org and inspect the payload received

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

This might solve your issue:

```
import requests
import json

api_url = 'http://11.111.11/index.php/Api/xxx/'
payload = {'key1':'KEY',
            'company1': 'company',
            'period1': 'period1',
             'header': "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
             'method': 'POST'}

headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

# Method 1
r = requests.post(url=api_url, data=payload, headers=headers)

# Method 2
r = requests.post(url=api_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations, it might help the OP and future visitors better understand your solution.

Comment: Sure, I will. Little occupied with some stuff at the moment.
Also, I was waiting for the response from the author, to whether or not this works. Otherwise, I will have to update the code.

Comment: Thanks, but the first solution gives a Status Code 500, and the second one gives an error in the json (same problem I was having before)

Comment: Status Code 500 is generally not related to your script, "The 500 Internal Server Error is a "server-side" error, meaning the problem is not with your PC or Internet connection but instead is a problem with the web site's server." Please contact API vendors, maybe some parameter is missing that they required or something is wrong at their end. and Do google about status 500. 
Json dump method works if API host accepts that as a valid input.